# How to download file in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

My download method is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {

            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename not present");

            var path = Path.Combine(
                           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot" + @"\UploadFiles", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

and view.chtml and route with filepath

```
<a asp-action="Download"
                   asp-route-filename="@item.UploadFilePath">
                    Download
                </a>
```

@item.UploadFilePath is database saved path.please help me.

Comment: Why `javascript` `jquery` tagged?

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Answer (score 6):

you can try this also

```
return File(path, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Comment: hi teacher my above of code is local running in download ok but iis server uploaded and download problem.why.....

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filepath);
return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code for download file from wwwroot

```
 public IActionResult DownloadAttachment(string attachment)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(
           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\UploadFile\\Journal",attachment);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", attachment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on URL `/Files?fileName=image.png`, file `image.png` must be placed in `wwwroot`.

```
public class FilesModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

    public FilesModel(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public PhysicalFileResult OnGet(string fileName)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Files", fileName);
        return new PhysicalFileResult(path, "image/png"); // Change to the right mime type
    }
}
```